# Why do you get electric field of a light wave?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, waves, electric-fields

Why do you get electric field of a light wave in following form: $E(x,t)=A cos(kx-\omega t- \theta)$?( look at: https://public.me.com/ricktrebino -> OpticsI-02-Waves-Fields.ppt, p. 18)

Comment: Far from the source, the propagating wave has a spherical form and propagates along the radius. So its local amplitude is a harmonic function of time. As to the coordinate dependence, it is something like $E=\frac{E_0}{R}\cdot cos(\vec{k}\vec{R}-\omega t - \theta)$. If R changes within $\delta R \approx 1/k<<R$, the R-dependence of the amplitude is weak (nearly constant), so locally you have a plane wave in direction of $\vec{R}$.

Answer (score 4):

As it happens I've just been reading "[17 Equations That Changed the World](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Seventeen-Equations-that-Changed-World/dp/1846685311)" by Ian Stewart and he gives the derivation. I strongly recommend the book, but if you just want the derivation you can find it [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_wave_equation#The_origin_of_the_electromagnetic_wave_equation). Since we're not supposed to just give links I'll copy the stuff from Wikipedia here:

Start with Maxwell's equations:

$$ \nabla \cdot \boldsymbol{E} = 0$$
$$ \nabla \times \boldsymbol{E} = -\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{B}}{\partial t}$$
$$ \nabla \cdot \boldsymbol{B} = 0$$
$$ \nabla \times \boldsymbol{B} = \mu_0\epsilon_0\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{E}}{\partial t}$$

Taking the curl of the curl equation for $\boldsymbol{E}$ gives:

$$ \nabla \times (\nabla \times \boldsymbol{E}) = -\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \nabla \times \boldsymbol{E}  = -\mu_0\epsilon_0\frac{\partial^2 \boldsymbol{E}}{\partial t^2}$$

But for any vector space $\boldsymbol{V}$ there is an identity:

$$\nabla \times (\nabla \times \boldsymbol{V}) = \nabla(\nabla \cdot \boldsymbol{V}) - \nabla^2 \boldsymbol{V}$$

so
$$\nabla \times (\nabla \times \boldsymbol{E}) = \nabla(\nabla \cdot \boldsymbol{E}) - \nabla^2 \boldsymbol{E} = - \nabla^2 \boldsymbol{E}$$

because $\nabla \cdot \boldsymbol{E} = 0$ so:

$$\nabla^2 \boldsymbol{E} = \mu_0\epsilon_0\frac{\partial^2 \boldsymbol{E}}{\partial t^2}$$

and this is just the wave equation:

$$ c^2\nabla^2 \boldsymbol{E}  = \frac{\partial^2 \boldsymbol{E}}{\partial t^2}$$

where $\mu_0\epsilon_0$ is equal to $c^{-2}$, $c$ is the speed of light.

You wanted to know why

$$\boldsymbol{E}(x,t)=\boldsymbol{A} \cos(kx-\omega t- \theta)$$

is one possible equation for a light wave, well substitute it into the equation above and you get:

$$ -c^2 \boldsymbol{A} k^2 \cos(kx-\omega t- \theta) = -\boldsymbol{A} \omega^2 \cos(kx-\omega t- \theta)$$

and obviously this satifies the wave equation if $c = \omega/k$. This is one solution of the wave equation, but of course there are lots of others.

Comment: Hmm, but doesn't the amplitude factor out and get cancelled here?

Comment: @Manishearth: I spotted an error and was editing my post while you commented. Does your comment still apply?

Comment: unfortunately, yes, since it still doesn't determine $A$. Unless I've misinterpreted the question--which I now think I have :/ . I thought the OP wanted the relation between a given light wave and the equation. +1 then :)

Comment: $A$ is just an arbitrary constant isn't it? It's the intensity of the light wave, but the wave can be any intensity.

Comment: The wave amplitude $A$ is determined either with the boundary conditions or with the source in the field equation. In your case (no source) it is the boundary conditions that "supply" the wave amplitude.

Comment: @John really? It can't be the intensity, since you can adjust E and B to your needs as long as the total energy is the same. Not sure of this, see my answer:/

Comment: @Manishearth: maybe we have different interpretations of what the OP is asking. His equation is a solution to the wave equation and in that solution $A$ is an arbitrary constant. I don't understand why we'd be worried about what value $A$ has.

Comment: @John, we _do_ have differ emt interpretations.. I thought he wanted to calculate the constants given the params of the wave. Your interpretation seems to be more correct :)

Answer (score 0):

If the light wave has frequency $\nu$, wavelength $\lambda$, then it becomes:

$$E=E_0\sin(\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}x-2\pi\nu t+\phi)$$

$\phi$ is arbitrary.

I'm not sure of this, but you can only calculate $E_0$ if you have the amplitude of magnetic field and the energy density of the wave($U$):

$$U=\frac12\epsilon_0E_0^2+\frac1{2\mu_0}E_0^2$$

Comment: shouldn't $nu$ be $T$ (period) ?